# CEF Chromium - How do I emulate/mimic the clicking on a link to invoke a Javascript function to populate a webpage

Tags: javascript, chromium, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Apologies. Am very, very new to CEF & Javascript.

I have loaded a page with CEF in a VB.Net app & can see

```
<a href="#" onclick="return cjs.Api.loader.get('cjs').call(function(_cjs){AddDetails(_cjs);});">Add Details</a>
```

in the source. When I click on the displayed page it adds/shows more details.

How can I action programmatically?

I have tried with

```
Call JSEvaluateScript(oBrowser, "return cjs.Api.loader.get('cjs').call(function(_cjs){AddDetails(_cjs);});")
```

with first, the JSEvaluateScript returning a string & secondly an object

```
Private Function JSEvaluateScript(ByRef oBrowser As ChromiumWebBrowser, ByVal sScript As String) As Object
    Dim oResult = oBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(sScript)
    oResult.Wait()
    Dim oResponse = oResult.Result
    JSEvaluateScript = IIf(oResponse.Success, oResponse.Result, nothing)
End Function
```

but neither have shown anymore details.

When called with the "return" prefix oResult.Result shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
@ about:blank:1:0". Without, it doesn't error but doesn't show anymore details either.

How do I emulate/mimic the clicking on the "Add Details" link created by the  &  ?

Comment: Are you using CefSharp? Please add the tag for which CEF wrapper you are using.

Comment: Yes. CEFSharp added.

Comment: Using EvaluateScriptAsync is similar to executing code in DevTools, you don't include a return statement, try something simple like executing 1 + 1 to confirm you get two. I'd suggest using DevTools to run the script and see how it behaves https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Comment: Have got devTools started.

Comment: Have added DevTools. Tested successfully with 1+1.
Have tried calling. No change. Still nothing added.
Noticed routine "sensed" position of display & added below if at the bottom LoadMoreDetails.
Positioned at the bottom of the page. Called routine. Still nothing added.
How can I use DevTools to step through the called routines? Any docs available?

Comment: Any of Chrome DevTools docs should be relevant.